# Where are the user friendly Wi-Fi names in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: wireless

When I was using Ubuntu 16.04 I could save an user friendly name to every known Wi-Fi network, because not always the SSID makes sense to know whose network it is.

This was extremely helpful to me. Now I've updated to Ubuntu 17.10 and I can't see these names any more. Where can I find these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default GUI network manager does't provide any option to change the name. But there's another tool you can use.

Open Terminal and run

```
nm-connection-editor
```

A connection editor will appear which allows you to change the connection name.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the GUI from 16.04, why did they change that?

But this has all that I was asking for, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This changed because Ubuntu 17.10 came with GNOME shell instead of Unity like before.

Comment: Sorry, thought I did but I didn't. Done now. I know this is because of GNOME, but I don't like it! ;-)